# TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, pyodbc, google-sheets-api

I have written a python script using PYODBC to pull data from a production DB and create a Google Sheet from that data. Everything works up to the point of writing the data to the newly created Google Sheet. I am getting this error:

TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable

I thought at first this was related to the dates included in my query results, but removing them did not change the error.

I am new to Python and even newer to Google Sheets API. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pyodbc
server = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'
database = 'TestDB'
username = 'XXXXXX'
password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'    
import time


from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
SHEETS = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

data = {'properties': {'title': 'FirstTest [%s]' % time.ctime()}}
res = SHEETS.spreadsheets().create(body=data).execute()
SHEET_ID = res['spreadsheetId']
print('Created "%s"' % res['properties']['title'])

FIELDS = ('Service.ID', 'ServiceDate', 'Invoice_ID', 'IsPaid', 'OrderID', 'CustomerName', 'JobID', 'ParentJob_ID', 'ParentTask_ID', 'Worker_ID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Tip')
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT ScheduledService.ID, ScheduledService.ServiceDate, ScheduledService.Invoice_ID, ScheduledService.IsPaid, JobDetails.OrderID, JobDetails.Name, Job.ID AS JobID, Job.ParentJob_ID, Job.ParentTask_ID, JobAssignmentEntry.Worker_ID, [User].FirstName, [User].LastName, ScheduledService.Tip FROM ScheduledService INNER JOIN JobDetails ON ScheduledService.ID = JobDetails.OrderID INNER JOIN Job ON JobDetails.ID = Job.ID INNER JOIN JobAssignmentEntry ON Job.ParentJob_ID = JobAssignmentEntry.Job_ID INNER JOIN EmployeeDataNew ON JobAssignmentEntry.Worker_ID = EmployeeDataNew.ID INNER JOIN [User] ON EmployeeDataNew.ID = [User].ID WHERE (ScheduledService.ServiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DY,-49,GetDate()) AND DATEADD(DY,-1,GetDate())) AND (ScheduledService.Service_ID IN (23, 24))")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
cnxn.close()
rows.insert(0, FIELDS)
data = {'values'}

SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=SHEET_ID,
    range='A1', body=data, valueInputOption='RAW').execute()
print('Wrote data to Sheet:')
rows = SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SHEET_ID,
    range='Sheet1').execute().get('values', [])
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Users\Scott\Documents\Python\WeeklyAsystantRestaurantDeliveries_CSV.py", line 38, in <module>
        range='A1', body=data, valueInputOption='RAW').execute()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 785, in method
        actual_path_params, actual_query_params, body_value)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\model.py", line 151, in request
        body_value = self.serialize(body_value)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\model.py", line 260, in serialize
        return json.dumps(body_value)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
        return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
        o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: `data = {'values'}` is a set; did you mean to make a dictionary instead perhaps? You are trying to send that set to Google via `SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().update(..., body=data, ...)`.

Comment: That could be my problem, but that is where my inexperience with python and google sheets API is giving me trouble. I followed a tutorial from Google on setting this up.

Comment: This is the tutorial I used: http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-new-google-sheets-api.html

Comment: Martijn - how is this question off-topic? I have documented the exact problem I have and tagged this to the google-sheets-api I am having problems with.

Comment: Take a closer look at your tutorial versus what you've posted with regard to the line that Martijin mentioned that is causing  your problem-- data = {'values'}.  You're creating a set with that line.  That's not what you want nor what the tutorial is demonstrating. The tutorial is creating a dictionary with "values" as a key and a list of row elements as the value--   data = {'values': [row[:6] for row in rows]}.  Long story short-- replace data = {'values'} with something like data = {'values': rows}

Comment: clockwatcher - Thanks for the tip. I have been trying various combinations since i posted the question earlier. I had not tried your suggestion specifically, but I had replaced that line-- data={'values'} with data={'values': [row[:13] for row in rows]} and it produces the same error as before. I just tried your suggestion and still get the same error. I am still working on different options, but so far every attempt I have made to fix this results in an error.

Comment: The `data = {'values'}` line was the only place you're creating a `set`, so at a minimum I'd expect a *different* error if you changed that line. Can you double check that you've actually applied your fix properly (e.g. saved the file, re-run the script, etc.).

Comment: Blcknght - You are correct, I had not applied the update correctly and it was cause the error. I have re-applied the fix now with data={'values': [row[:13] for row in rows]} and the original error message has disappeared. Now I am getting an error related to the date field not being JSON serializable. I will have to start a new question to go through that issue and figure out a resolution.